Invalid display metrics in Android 9
I have two computers, Odroid C2 with Android 5.1.1 and Odroid C4 with Android 9.0. Both have the same display and video controller, 1280x800. I run the same code on both computers:
Resources r = MainActivity.getInstance().getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = r.getDisplayMetrics();

and see very different result. On Android 5.1.1:
heightPixels = 1232
widthPixels = 800
xdpi = 160.157
ydpi = 160.0
density = 1.0
densityDpi = 160
scaledDensity = 1.0

On Android 9.0:
heightPixels = 1219
widthPixels = 800
xdpi = 0.0
ydpi = 0.0
density = 1.275
densityDpi = 204
scaledDensity = 1.08375

My software was originally written on Android 5.1.1 but it was ordered not wery well (some dimensions in pixels etc). When I migrated on Odroid C4 with Android 9.0 some text sizes looked invalid. I switched the text size to smallest in Android settings and all text sizes became correct. But now I need to fit the app all Android rules and adopt the app to some other screen sizes. So I neen the correct display metrics data from the system.
What did I wrong? Why is the display metrics incorrect? How can I fix this?
Great thanks for any answer!
